# Some questions about Google Maps Api and fusion tables

Tags: joomla, google-maps-api-3

I am doing some research about google maps api, I am trying to implement a map with different categories of objects a according to a button it will display all the locations of certain category. I am using Joomla. I read this tutorial, http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html.

It seems doable, but I have some questions regarding google maps. I leave in Ecuador and many streets are not listed exactly. Is it possible to mark a location manually, like dragging the marker?  So if it is not positionated correctly it can be corrected.

Also, I have being reading a lot about fusion tables. Is it advisable to use them with Joomla. Will it have any advantage, or it is just another layer to the programming and design. Are mysql and fusion tables mutually exclusive, so if i use fusion tables I dont need to have the same tables in mysql?